# getting error on passing argument for ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#

In below C# code, I'm getting error,

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("logman.exe")
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                Arguments = "FabricTraces | findstr Root",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            Process proc = Process.Start(psi); ;
            StreamReader myOutput = proc.StandardOutput;
            proc.WaitForExit(20000);
            if (proc.HasExited)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( myOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
```

Error,

```
Argument '|' is unknown.
Argument 'findstr' is unknown.
Argument 'Root' is unknown.
```

I need to pass below argument, how to do it? Thanks for your answer.

```
FabricTraces | findstr Root
```

Output in Console,

C:>logman.exe FabricTraces | findstr Root
Root Path:            C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric\Fabric\log\Traces\

C:>

Comment: its separated arguments?
You could try 
`Arguments = "FabricTraces, |, findstr, Root"`
or `Arguments = "'FabricTraces | findstr Root'"`

Comment: it's a filter to get only one value

Comment: still the error is same

Comment: What makes you think that  `"FabricTraces | findstr Root"` is a valid argument for `logman.exe`?

Comment: FabricTraces is one of the data collector set name. If we just do "logman.exe FabricTraces", the more than one output. To limit with one I added a filter

Comment: I don't see that command line option in [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490956.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)... The `|` character in the documentation is being used to indicate `"or"` when specifying the allowable parameters.

Comment: you probably want "cmd /c logman.exe FabricTraces | findstr \"Root\"" as your entire command as cmd deals with pipes.

Comment: `findstr` is separate application (executable). What you are trying to do here is run `logman FabricTraces` and then redirect output of this process to `findstr Root` via pipe ("|"). But pipe is cmd specific thing, so it cannot work like this. Instead run "cmd.exe" as above comment suggests.

Comment: Thanks Evk, it's works

Comment: It's important to be careful to make sure the right process is interpreting your command line arguments. Your attempt sends the entire text, including the piped `| findstr...`, as arguments to the program `logman.exe`. Which, of course, doesn't have any idea what to do with that. You need to pass all that to `cmd.exe`, per marked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`ProcessStartInfo` accepts  Arguments with spaces inside quotes and interpreted them as multiple arguments.So you should wrap it with the double quote. (As I understand you should pass one argument to the process)

```
        startInfo.Arguments = "\"FabricTraces | findstr Root\"";
```

Now it should be treated as a one argument not 3 space separated ones.

Comment: Thanks, but getting error... The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: have you specified the path to logman.exe?

Comment: Yes, C:\Windows\System32\logman.exe